# How to update a branch via master using Git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am a complete newbie when it comes to Git and am struggling to understand how handle merges on branches.

Basically I have branchA which has some changes, master (which I'm trying to use as analog to "trunk" in SVN) and branchB. What I am trying to do is update master with changes from branchA, then update branchB using those changes. Then create branchC based on master.

Or at least that's what would do using SVN.

Lost in the woods, I know there's plenty of info ou there, but there's a little too much for this task I need done atm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master                 <-- change to master
git merge branchA                   <-- merge changes from branchA into master
git checkout branchB                <-- change to branchB
git merge master                    <-- merge changes from master & branchA into branchB
git checkout master -b branchC      <-- create a new branch called branchC based on master
```

I assume all the commands don't cause conflicts.

Comment: Yup! why don't you just try it?

Comment: When I do git merge branchA, git complains "fatal: 'branchA' does not point to a commit"

Comment: Hmm.. This didn't do anything at all. When I did a push I got this

   $ git push
   Password: 
   Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To https://xxxxxxxx/git/xxxxxxx
      4c7e0e8..2c03ac3  master -> master

When I try to checkout the new branch, git says it doesn't exist, which doesn't surprise me considering..

Comment: You can use `git log` to make sure that the changes are merged before doing `git push`. but `origin/branchA` is different from `branchA`. `origin/branchA` contains the changes you get from remote repos in your last `git pull` or `git fetch`.

Comment: Ok, looks like I got the branchB updated, but can't get the branchC to remote for some reason